# Disable Confirm Button onclick - Duplicate actions

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click that button repeatedly, it performs the same action repeatedly. Does anyone know a way to disable the confirmation button after the first click?

```
    $('#btn-executar-procedimento').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Confirm this",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Confirm!",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: true
        }, function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {
                $('#executar-form').submit();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [unbind() function](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) like this

```
 $('#btn-executar-procedimento').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Hi @Ivil. It didn't work. When I double-click, it doubles the action yet.

Comment: @Thiagossnet, I have tried a simplified version:   
$('#btn-executar-procedimento').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $(this).unbind('click');
    alert('clicked');
    });

And it perfectly worked. Maybe that swal() function does something?

Comment: @Ivil It's a proprietary function called sweetalert (sweetalert.js.org), but they dont support by what I researched. I'm still looking at a way to lock the button after the first click.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Solutions are possible:

1.) Just put a boolean and change the value as soon as someone has clicked the button first time and of course check for it :)

2.) If you really don't want to show that again then remove/unbind the action handler. (But what happens if someone cancels the popup, then you would need again the handler)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pretty simple. Just disable the button after the first click using `disabled` property:

```
$('#btn-executar-procedimento').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Confirm this",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Confirm!",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: true
    }, function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
            $('#executar-form').submit();

            //disable the button
            $('#btn-executar-procedimento').disabled = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @KienHT. It didn't work. When I double-click, it doubles the action yet.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many solutions but the easy and best ones are

1. To use CSS

   1.Hide the button if not needed further using **display: none**

   2.You can also use **pointer-events: none**.

2.Disabled attribute once the function call is done.
//disable the button after submit

```
        $('#btn-executar-procedimento').disabled = true;
```

3.Use JS to unbind the event/action
remove/unbind the action handler.

```
 $(this).unbind('click');
```

There is the other method also but these are the easiest ones.

```
$('#btn-executar-procedimento').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Confirm this",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Confirm!",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: true
        }, function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {
                $('#executar-form').submit();

              **//ALL LOGIC HERE AFTER SUBMIT** 
             
                  
            }
        });
```